# mongodb insertOne inside a loop

Tags: mongodb, loops, insert

I want to insert different collections inside a loop.
I already wrote this and it works once.

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

let insertflowers = async (collectionname,query) => {
    try {
        await client.connect();
        const database = client.db('flowers');
        const collection = database.collection(collectionname);
        return await collection.insertOne(query);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}

insertflowers('alocasias',{name:'...'}).catch(console.dir);
```

What I want to do is put it inside a loop like this.

```
arrayofflowers.forEach( val => {
    let flowerType = ...
    insertflowers(flowerType,{name:'...'}).catch(console.dir);
});
```

But I get the following error
**MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect**
Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1):

In short remove `await client.close();`

---

Check https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/insertMany/ to insert bulk records at once.

---

You're in race condition so when insertflowers process is running in parallel connection is closed and opening.

So when you try to insert data connection is closed by another call to insertflowers.

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

let connection;

const connect = async () => {
  if (!connection) { // return connection if already connected
    connection = await client.connect();
  }
  return connection;
});

let insertflowers = async (collectionname,query) => {
    try {
        const conn = await connect();
        const database = conn.db('flowers');
        const collection = database.collection(collectionname);
        return await collection.insertOne(query);
    } finally {
        console.log('insertflowers completed');
        // await client.close(); remove this
    }
}
```

---

Another option - Not a good idea though

Make `insertflowers` is run the sync.